# Matrix filling for the Smith-Waterman algorithm in CUDA

Tags: algorithm, cuda

I need an advice on how optimizing my implementation of the Smith-Waterman algorithm in CUDA.

The part which I want to optimize is filling the matrix. Due to the data dependence between matrix elements (each next element depends on the other ones - left to it, up to it, and left-up to it), I'm filling anti-diagonal matrix elements in parallel, as illustrated in the picture below:

[image]

My program operates in a loop as

```
int diag = 1;
for(int x = 0; x < size_b; x++)
{
    block_size = 1024;
    if(block_size > diag)
    {
        block_size = diag;
    }
    SAFE_KERNEL_CALL((dev_init_diag<<<(diag - 1)/block_size + 1, block_size>>>(H, size_a, size_b, x,
                      sequence_a, sequence_b, false, x_offset, y_offset, null_ind)));
    diag++;
}
```

As you can see, there is one kernel call for each diagonal.

Since I have quite large matrices (with `21000` elements on side), there are a lot of kernel calls. As a result, I have a large overhead for CUDA kernel calls, wasting about half of the processing time, which can be seen by the screenshot of the Visual Profiler (look at Profiler overhead string):

[image]

So, the question is *how to get rid of multiple kernel calls and to eliminate this overheads*.

There is one important thing to notice:
The reason why I call a new kernel for each diagonal is that I need to synchronize the threads and blocks before the next call and, as I understand, there is an only way to syncronize CUDA blocks - to finish the kernel and start it again. Nevertheless, for this algorithm there might be a better solution.

Thank You for reading this!

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

ok, thank you for your response!
one more question, more about CUDA:
so, I have to implement a new kernel, probably like this:

```
__global__ void kernel(...)
{
for(int diag_num = 0; diag_num < size; diag_num++)
{
    init_one_diag(...);
    syncronize_threads();
}
}
```

but that means I have to launch this kernel only on one cuda-block?(because as I know there is no syncronization between different blocks)

before I have launched kernels this way:

dev_init_diag<<<(diag - 1)/block_size + 1, block_size>>>(...)

will be new approach as efficient?

Comment: you can try dynamic parallelism?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend going through the available literature to implement an efficient approach to the matrix filling problem for the Smith-Waterman algorithm.

From the description of your code, you are choosing to parallel filling anti-diagonals and you are launching one kernel for each anti-diagonal. As you mentioned, this is quite ineffective due to the multiple kernel launches.

A simple alternative is constructing a single kernel function in charge of calculating all the anti-diagonals. This kernel should be launched with a number of threads at least equal to the longest anti-diagonal. The kernel performs a number of iterations equal to the number of anti-diagonals to be calculated. For anti-diagonals shorter than the longest one, only a subset of threads remains active. This approach is described in

[Parallelizing the Smith-Waterman Local Alignment Algorithm using CUDA](http://heather.cs.ucdavis.edu/~matloff/158/cudasw.pdf)

but is ineffective for two reasons:

1. Most of the threads remain unactive for a significant number of computations (anti-diagonals);
2. The memory accesses are highly uncoalesced.

An alternative to anti-diagonal matrix filling is provided by the approach in

[Acceleration of the Smith–Waterman algorithm using single and multiple graphics processors](http://www.nvidia.com/content/cudazone/CUDABrowser/downloads/papers/Acceleration_of_the_SmithWaterman_algorithm_using_single.pdf)

There it is shown how how the Smith–Waterman (anti-diagonal) matrix filling algorithm can be reformulated so that the calculations can be performed in parallel one row (or column) at a time. It is underlined how row (or column) calculations allow the GPU memory accesses to be consecutive (coalesced) and therefore fast. Although not explicitly mentioned, I believe that this approach mitigates (or totally removes) also the above mentioned issue of unactive threads.

**EDIT**

The GPU Computing Gems book, Emerald Edition, dedicates two chapters to the Smith-Waterman algorithm, namely,

Chapter 11, Accurate Scanning of Sequence Databases with the Smith-Waterman Algorithm

and

Chapter 13, GPU-Supercomputer Acceleration of Pattern Matching

The latter is a chapter from the same authors of the second mentioned approach. The former, contains a step-by-step derivation of an optimized CUDA code, which may result useful to future users.

Comment: thank you!
then, I have another question, and I posted it by editing my first message, in the end.(because this comments doesn`t support code pasting)

Comment: @IlyaAfanasiev Concerning your second question, I would suggest you to set up a code working on more than one block. Then you can tune the performance of your code, and in particular the block size, either by exploiting the CUDA occupancy calculator or by using a profiler (e.g., the Visual Profiler). I forgot mentioning a reference where you can find a step-by-step derivation of a CUDA implementation of the Smith-Waterman algorithm (see my edited post). Although it may serve more in the case of applying the algorithm to many sequences, it may be anyway of interest to you.